# Оптимизация генерации полного дерева игры

Tags: алгоритм, оптимизация, дерево

Здравствуйте! Есть задача - сгенерировать полное дерево для N-мерных крестиков ноликов. Пока данную задачу решает такой код:

```
 class GameTree:
  evaled = 0 # кол-во просчитанных листьев
  def __init__(self, players, points, cp=0, level=0): 
  # players - list(list(list(int))) - список игроков,
  #                             каждый игрок - список его ходов,
  #                             каждый ход - список его координат

  # points - list(list(int)) - список ходов,
  #                           каждый ход - список его координат

  # cp - int - индекс игрока, который сейчас ходит
  # level - int - номер хода в партии (используется для вывода) 
    GameTree.evaled += 1

    players = slist(deepcopy(players)) # чтобы не дать изменять исходный список
    points = slist(deepcopy(points)) 

    if cp == len(players): # если сходил последний
      cp = 0

    self.children = []

    for i in players: # если кто-то уже выиграл 
      if won(i): 
        self.children = None
        return

    if points == []: # если нет ходов
      self.children = None
      return

    me = players[cp]
    enemies = players.without(players[cp])

    if len(me)>=2: # если уже можно выиграть
      for i in points:
        me_ = me + [i]

        if won(me_): # если можно выиграть, сделав ход i
          players[cp].append(i)
          self.children = GameTree(n, players, points.without(i), cp+1, level=level+1) # нужно совершить ход i
          return

    blocked = False

    for i in points:
      for en in enemies:
        en_ = en + [i]
        if won(en_): # если кто-то из противников может выиграть, совершив ход i
          buff = deepcopy(players) 
          players[cp].append(i)
          self.children.append(GameTree(players, points.without(i), cp+1, level=level+1)) # нужно попробовать ему помешать 
          players = buff
          blocked = True

    if blocked: # если кто-то мог выиграть
      return

    for i in points: # для каждого возможного хода
      buff = deepcopy(players)
      players[cp].append(i)
      self.children.append(GameTree(n, players, points.without(i), cp+1, level=level+1)) # попробовать, что получится
      players = buff
```

И все вроде хорошо, но уже для трех измерений и двух игроков дерево генерируется неприлично долго. Но, так как к одному и тому же состоянию поля можно прийти множеством разных путей, сейчас дерево выглядит, как на рис. 1. Было бы здорово превратить его в рис. 2. (извините, не могу объяснить это словами)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для этого был рожден такой вот монстр:

```
if str(players) in list(GameTree.nodes.keys()): # если есть в уже рассчитанных листьях, есть такое состояние поля
  self.children.append(GameTree.node[players]) # 'соединить' его с текущим
  return 
else:
  new = GameTree(players, points.without(i), cp+1, level=level+1) # рассчитать
  GameTree.nodes[str(players)] = new # запомнить
  self.children.append(new)
```

С ним код приобретает такой вид:

```
class GameTree:
  evaled = 0
  nodes = {}
  def __init__(self, players, points, cp=0, level=0):
    GameTree.evaled += 1
    players = slist(deepcopy(players))
    points = slist(deepcopy(points))

    if cp == len(players):
      cp = 0

    self.children = []

    for i in players:
      if won(i):
        self.children = None
        return

    if points == []:
      self.children = None
      return

    me = players[cp]
    enemies = players.without(players[cp])

    if len(me)>=2:
      for i in points:
        me_ = me + [i]

        if won(me_):
          players[cp].append(i)
          if str(players) in list(GameTree.nodes.keys()):
              self.children.append(GameTree.node[players])

          else:
              new = GameTree(players, points.without(i), cp+1, level=level+1)
              GameTree.nodes[str(players)] = new
              self.children.append(new)

          return

    blocked = False

    for i in points:
      for en in enemies:
        en_ = en + [i]
        if won(en_):
          buff = deepcopy(players) 
          players[cp].append(i)

          if str(players) in list(GameTree.nodes.keys()):
              self.children.append(GameTree.node[players])
              return
          else:
              new = GameTree(players, points.without(i), cp+1, level=level+1)
              GameTree.nodes[str(players)] = new
              self.children.append(new)

          players = buff
          blocked = True

    if blocked:
      return

    for i in points:
      buff = deepcopy(players)
      players[cp].append(i)

      if str(players) in list(GameTree.nodes.keys()):
        self.children.append(GameTree.node[str(players)])
        return  
      else:
        new = GameTree(players, points.without(i), cp+1, level=level+1)
        GameTree.nodes[str(players)] = new
        self.children.append(new)

      players = buff
```

Мало того, что код ужасен, он еще и не работает. Не могли бы вы помочь? 
Вот весь код, если он нужен (там еще куча некрасивых мест, если кто-нибудь расскажет, как его улучшить в плане стиля (а может даже и производительности), буду очень признателен):

```
from copy import deepcopy
from time import time
from threading import Thread
from math import factorial

point_class = lambda a: a.count(0)

class slist(list):
  def without(self, x):
    b = self[:]
    b.remove(x)
    return b

def to_ter_arr(i):
  if i<3:
    return [i]

  return to_ter_arr(i // 3) + [i%3]


def gen(n):
  ret = slist()

  for i in range(pow(3, n)):
    buff = to_ter_arr(i)
    buff = [0]*(n-len(buff))+buff
    buff = list(map(lambda a: a-1, buff))
    ret.append(buff)

  return ret

def three(a, b, c):
  if a == [] or b == [] or c== []:
    return False

  for i in range(len(a)):
    s = [a[i], b[i], c[i]]
    if not s in [[1,1,1], [-1,-1,-1], [0,0,0], [1,0,-1], [-1,0,1]]:
      return False

  return True and a!=b and a!=c and b!=c

def won(pl):
  for a in pl:
    for b in pl:
      for c in pl:
        if three(a, b, c):
          return True

  return False

def output(s):
  f.write(s+'\n')

class GameTree:
  evaled = 0
  def __init__(self, players, points, cp=0, level=0):
    GameTree.evaled += 1
    players = slist(deepcopy(players))
    points = slist(deepcopy(points))

    if cp == len(players):
      cp = 0

    self.children = []

    for i in players:
      if won(i):
        output('{}{} won {}'.format(' '*level, level, players.index(i)))
        self.children = None
        return

    if points == []:
      output('{}{} draw'.format(' '*level, level, 'draw'))
      self.children = None
      return

    me = players[cp]
    enemies = players.without(players[cp])

    if len(me)>=2:
      for i in points:
        me_ = me + [i]

        if won(me_):
          players[cp].append(i)
          output('{}{} {} {} next - win'.format(' '*level, level, cp, i))
          self.children = GameTree(players, points.without(i), cp+1, level=level+1)
          return

    blocked = False

    for i in points:
      for en in enemies:
        en_ = en + [i]
        if won(en_):
          buff = deepcopy(players) 
          players[cp].append(i)
          output('{}{} {} {} blocking {}'.format(' '*level, level, cp, i, players.index(en)))
          self.children.append(GameTree(players, points.without(i), cp+1, level=level+1))
          players = buff
          blocked = True

    if blocked:
      return

    for i in points:
      buff = deepcopy(players)
      players[cp].append(i)
      output('{}{} {} {} try'.format(' '*level, level, cp, i))
      self.children.append(GameTree(players, points.without(i), cp+1, level=level+1))
      players = buff

def progress():
  global aprox, game, start
  while game.is_alive():
    print('\r{} / {}, {} s'.format(GameTree.evaled, aprox, time()-start), end='')


n = int(input('N = '))
points = gen(n)
aprox = factorial(len(points))

pc = int(input('Количество игроков: '))
center = slist([0 for i in range(n)])
players = slist([[center]]+[[] for i in range(pc-1)])

file_name = input('Имя файла: ')
f = open(file_name, 'w')

show = input('Показывать прогресс (Д\Н, Д по умолчанию)')

if show == 'H' or show == 'н':
  show = False

elif show == 'Д' or show == 'д' or show == '':
  show = True

else:
  print('Ошибка!!!')
  exit(1)
print('\nCenter =', center)
print('Players =', players)
print('Points =', points)
print('Aproximate number of leaves:', aprox)
start = time()

output('0 0 [0, 0] root')

game = Thread(target = GameTree, kwargs = {'players': players, 'points': points.without(center), 'cp': 1, 'level': 1})
prog = Thread(target = progress)

game.start()
if show:
  prog.start()

else:
  game.join()

  print(time()-start, 's')
```