# Ускорение генерации большого дерева

Tags: алгоритм, оптимизация, дерево

Здравствуйте! Есть задача - сгенерировать очень большое дерево за разумное время. Пока пишу на питоне, но это не так важно. Алгоритм примерно такой:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, array1, array2):
        self.state = deepcopy(array1)
        self.children = []

        if finished(array1) or finished(array2):
            return

        if last_cond(array1):
            last_modify_1(array1)
            last_modify_2(array2)

            self.children = Tree(array1, array2)
            return

        for a in array1:
            if cond_a(a):
                modify_a_1(array1, a)
                modify_a_2(array2, a)

                self.children.append(Tree(array1, array2))

        for b in array2:
            if cond_b(b):
                modify_b_1(array1, b)
                modify_b_2(array2, b)

                self.children.append(Tree(array1, array2))
```

Очевидно, что результатом работы данного куска кода будет дерево, которое изображено на рис. 1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такое дерево **очень** большое - в нем легко может быть `26!` листьев, но уникальных из них - "всего" несколько сотен тысяч. 
Ни о каком разумном времени говорить даже не приходится.

Нужно оптимизировать, причем радикально.

Вопрос первый: как сразу генерировать дерево, изображенное на рис. 2?

Вопрос второй: так в приведенном выше алгоритме одна ветвь не зависит от другой, их, наверное, можно просчитывать параллельно (параллельным программированием я почти не занимался). Может ли это помочь? Если может, скажите, в какую сторону копать.

Есть ли еще какие-нибудь способы оптимизации?

Сама задача, на всякий случай: построить полное дерево для n-мерных крестиков-ноликов для m-игроков. Я уже задавал этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628862/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B), там же есть весь код.

Comment: На рисунке 2 изображено не дерево.

Comment: Да, извините, рисунок кривой. Имел в виду, что третий лист был посчитан, как ребенок первого; а второй хранит ссылку на третий. Или это тоже не дерево? Как тогда его называть?

Comment: DAG - directed acyclic graph. Направленный ациклический граф. Структура часто возникает при работе с деревьями.

Comment: а какая ваша исходная задача? Может тут вообще не нужны деревья? Мне кажется что это может быть XY - проблема.